# Finding $a$ and $b$ such that the graph of $y=-2\sin3x+1$ passes through $(-\frac\pi{12},a)$ and $(b,1)$

Tags: trigonometry

Please look at the attached image through the link. I already figured out $b$, which I'm pretty sure is $2\pi/3$. However, I'm confused on figuring out $a$. This is what I tried:

\begin{align*}
y & = -2\sin(3x)+1\\
y & = -2\sin\left(3 \cdot -\frac{\pi}{12}\right)+1\\
y & = -2\sin\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+1
\end{align*}
I used the unit circle to find $\sin\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$.
\begin{align*}
y & = -2\left(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)+1\\
y & =  \sqrt{2} + 1\\
y & = 2.41421356
\end{align*}

My answer isn't correct, so could anyone please explain how I should solve for $b$? Thanks!

[image: diagram]

Comment: No image-questions please. Type them in Latex.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Your value of $\sqrt{2} + 1$ for $a$ is correct.  However, you should write $y \approx 2.41421356$.  How did you obtain $2\pi/3$ for $b$?  Your answer for $b$ should be in the interval $[\pi/4, \pi/2]$.

Comment: Note that $\pi/2 < 2\pi/3 < 3\pi/4$, which would put $(2\pi/3,1)$ at a different place in the graph than the point shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct value for $a$. Perhaps it was marked incorrect if you entered your approximation rather than the exact value of $\sqrt{2}+1$.

For $b$, you can simply let $y=1$ and solve:

$$y=-2\sin(3x)+1$$

$$1=-2\sin(3b)+1$$

$$-2\sin(3b)=0$$

$$\sin(3b)=0$$

In your diagram, it looks like $\frac{\pi}{4}<b<\frac{\pi}{2}$. Use your unit circle to determine which values of $3b$ produce $\sin(3b)=0$, and find a value of $b$ that satisfies both $\sin (3b) = 0$ and $\frac{\pi}{4}<b<\frac{\pi}{2}$. Your answer of $b=\frac{2\pi}{3}$ satisfies the first criterion, but not the second.

Answer (score 0):

To find b simply let $1 = -2\sin(3x) +1$ and it is when $\sin3x = 0$ for the some $\frac{\pi}{4} < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$
Since $\arcsin(0) \in (0, \pi, 2\pi...) $ you may obtain $x = 0, \frac{\pi}{3}, \frac{2\pi}{3}...$ from which clearly $\frac{\pi}{3}$ is the desired value

To find a is a similiar method, let $a = 1 - 2\sin(-\frac{\pi}{4})$ such that $ a = 1 + \sqrt{2}$